# Rails remote delete and update view through Ajax

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.2, partial-views

In the past, whenever I wanted to update a part of my view through Ajax, I've done the following:

1. create a partial out of the part I want to update and give it a unique ID, say `#tracks`
2. create a special action in the controller for that Ajax call, say `remove_track` that updates all the values, etc. and add `format.js`
3. create a new JS file with the same name as the action so Rails calls it automatically `remove_track.js.erb` which contains something like: `$('#tracks').html("<%=j render 'cds/show_tracks' %>");`
4. set `remote: true` in the link that calls this action.

All this is fine, but now I am trying to delete and update a common `index` view using the regular `destroy` method for flexibility, meaning I can call this method either through Ajax or normally. I figured it's such a common thing to do that there has to be a better way than all of the above.

I can get the destroy method to call my `destroy.js.erb` file by simply putting this into the controller:

```
  format.js { layout: false }
```

and of course setting `remote: true` on the link.

what I cannot do is get the view to refresh. The table I want to refresh is encased in a div with a unique ID, but since it's not a partial, it refuses to refresh the content. Maybe I'm missing something.

Am I doomed to have to create a partial and refresh it with the method above or is there a more magical way of doing it (other than using Turbolinks)?

Thanks.

**PS**
Also, I just noticed this has the added disadvantage that I cannot pass the rest of the params to the destroy method since it only passes the object ID to destroy using the regular CRUD routes. If I try to use `platform(action: destroy)` or `platform(method: delete)` I get an error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"platforms"}
```

Which means I have to create a new route if I want to pass those parameters...

Yet another disadvantage to all this is that I'm repeading all the logic for searches and sorting that I have in the index method again in the destroy method. I am certain this is **definitely not** the way to do it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Thanks to this page I found the proper way to do it. So simple and effective.

http://carmennorahgraydean.blogspot.com.es/2012/10/rails-328-ajax-super-basic-example.html

> Update your destroy line in index.html.erb:
>
> ```
> <%= link_to 'Destroy', pony, method: :delete, data: { confirm:
> 'Are you sure?' }, :remote => true, :class => 'delete_pony' %>
> ```
>
> Create a file, destroy.js.erb, put it next to your other .erb files
>   (under app/views/ponies). It should look like this:
>
> ```
> $('.delete_pony').bind('ajax:success', function() {     
>   $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut();
> });
> ```
>
> Add format.js { render :layout => false } to your controller:
>
> ```
> respond_to do |format|
>  format.html { redirect_to ponies_url }
>  format.json { head :no_content }
>  format.js   { render :layout => false }
> end
> ```

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Thanks much. This worked perfectly for me. You should probably mark it as the accepted answer or write the code in the answer here.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, it really helped me. External blog posts have a nasty habit of disappearing, so I edited your answer to include the relevant code just in case.