# Rails 4 AJAX delete link in HAML

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

Given the following:
[image]

What is the HAML magic on making such a thing work? I found [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727004/rails-remote-delete-and-update-view-through-ajax) but of course it's an ERB file. And, my HAML skills are SORELY lacking (it's an inherited system). I also don't have any other examples in the app I can glom from, b/c right now the app is all 'view only'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
 = link_to "Delete", path(object), method: :delete, remote: true
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `view.haml` file

```
= link_to "Delete", your_delete_path(object), method: :delete, remote: true
```

and in `js.haml` file, if you want to return any response then simply write -

```
alert("deleted");
```

or you can render any response from here.

Hope this help!!